# Not able to find asp.net 3.0 in IIS

Tags: iis-6

I have installed VS 2008 on my win2k3 server and when i am try to create a new site in iis, but not able to find asp.net 3.0 version in dropdown list of asp.net version

Answer (score 0):

.NET 3 and 2.5 are .NET 2 plus extra assemblies.

Just select 2.0.x.